# How to remove previous added rectangle object in Fabric?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

On mouse click event, a rectangle is added to the canvas:

```
    canvas.on({
        'mouse:down': function(options) {
            canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
                left: options.e.clientX,
                top: options.e.clientY,
                fill: 'red',
                width: 20,
                height: 20
            }));
        }
    });
```

If I click somewhere else a second rectangle is drawn, and so on. I want the previous rectangle to be removed, for every new mouse click event.
I can't use animate() in this case, cause in my application there will be a lot of rectangles drawn and I need to just redraw new rectangles on new places, not moving every one of them.

In native canvas I could just use `clearRect()` to clear the whole canvas and redraw a new rectangle in the new place.  How can I do something like that when using Fabric.js?

Answer (score 1):

You could create only one rectangle object, and change its `left` and `top` position for subsequent mouse down events.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas',{selection:false});
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  fill: 'red',
  width: 20,
  height: 20,
  visible:false
});

canvas.add(rect);

canvas.on('mouse:down', function(options) {
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(options.e);
  rect.set({
    left: pointer.x,
    top: pointer.y,
    visible:true
  });
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

```css
canvas{
 border:2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id='canvas' width=500 height=400>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but i should say that is not exactly what i need . 
On event i need to change  coordinates of whole group of objects , not just one , so i solved my case this way :

1) after adding object to canvas , put it to list
 `listOfHexObjToRemove.push(rect)`
2) on event remove all these objects from canvas 
 `for ( i in listOfHexObjToRemove ) {
  canvas.remove(listOfHexObjToRemove[i])
 };`
3) create new obects with new coordinates.
I'm not sure this is the best way how to solve this problem , so  if anybody show better way -  it would be great .

Comment: @Vitozz_RDX how about creating a group? can you make a fiddle?